# Modify Endpoint Address of a WCF Client Proxy

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-client

When I'm making web service calls from Silverlight using a service reference, is there any way to have the (generated) SoapClient objects modify the address that they call the service on?

Specifically, I'd like to tack on a QueryString value onto each call that the service makes.  So if I have

`DataService.SilverlightServiceSoapClient C = new DataService.SilverlightServiceSoapClient();`

Is there any way to do something like:

```
C.Address += "?Foo=Bar";
```

Which would allow me to, from my WebMethod, say:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["foo"];`

Obviously I can modify my WebMethods to take this value in as a parameter, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using service references, you can simply use the overload of the proxy class constructor that accepts an EndpointAddress as a parameter. Alternatively, you can create multiple endpoint configuration and have the code simply use the chosen configuration - which may include URL changes.

See [Understanding Generated Client Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733881.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't think I asked the question very clearly.  I *am* using a service reference to call the asmx, and the generated proxy does not have a Uri property.  It does have the property C.Endpoint.Address.Uri, but trying to modify that did not go well.

Comment: Sorry.  Being clear is usually something I'm not terrible at.  I think the problem was I figured the only way to call an asmx service from Silverlight was to use a service reference.

How else *could* you do it?

Comment: @Adam: those of us who don't program Silverlight wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to do this is to just use one of the overloaded constructors and supply the uri yourself

```
C = new DataService.SilverlightServiceSoapClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://blah/blah/blah/SilverlightService.asmx?Foo=Bar"));
```

Comment: And of course store the Uri somewhere intelligent so it's not just hard-coded into your constructor...